# New contract deployment pattern (0x60c06040)?

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, signature, deployed-bytecode

I've been monitoring new contract deployments simply by looking for **leading** `0x60806040` pattern in a transaction's data field ([example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9b70d27d06e59561dcf01d1ca2a4ad4a73eeb859b5ac7ff5caab96fedf8c067b)).

However, I've noticed there is a similar pattern that is less common, i.e. `0x60c06040` ([example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe1292032c43db94639f3666d2eb66a1b5a5692c6b44d6b201f490c319f5da1bd)).

My questions:

1. What is the difference between those two patterns?
2. Are there any other patterns that signal a new contract deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: To your question nr.2, I have spotted a somewhat different pattern but I cannot fully explain it besides telling the opcodes and the data. The pattern starts with `0x61088480`. I already opened a thread asking about it and I am waiting for proper explanation: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144323/contracts-being-deployed-via-0x61088480/144349#144349

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've been monitoring new contract deployments simply by looking for
> leading 0x60806040 (truncated keccak signature) in a transaction's
> data field (example).

This is not a signature, but the memory initialization bytecode:

- 0x60 : [PUSH1](https://www.ethervm.io/#PUSH1)
- 0x80
- 0x60 : [PUSH1](https://www.ethervm.io/#PUSH1)
- 0x40

This should be followed by 0x52 ([MSTORE](https://www.ethervm.io/#52)) to write 0x80 at memory location 0x40, initializing the free memory pointer as per the solidity [memory layout specifications](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory).

> What is the difference between those two patterns?

The first one initializes the free memory pointer to its default value (0x80) while the second one initializes it to 0xC0, thus pre-allocating 64 bytes of memory - or two 32 bytes slots.

This allocation pattern is due to how the Solidity compiler reserves memory for immutables (32 bytes slots each). This means that the value to push on the stack changes based on how many immutables the smart contract contains: 0x80 if there are no immutables, 0xa0 with one immutable, 0xc0 with two immutables, and so on.

> Are there any other patterns that signal a new contract deployment?

This one is simply not a contract's deployment transaction pattern. The pattern you are looking for is :

- tx.to is null (ommitted)
- tx.data is not empty

This is only valid for transactions that deploy smart contracts, not for smart contracts deploying other smart contracts.

You could further refine it by looking into the tx receipt or for some special [CODECOPY](https://www.ethervm.io/#39) opcodes patterns in the deployment bytecode, as I explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/126797/84305), but if all you want is to do is log them that might not be necessary.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Adding to your answer. I agree with your deployment detection pattern. Also @pcko1, notice that there are other transaction data that start with the same pattern. You can look up the signature [`0x60c06040`](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x60806040) on 4byte.directory. These functions can be used to trick monitoring bots like yours into thinking a new contract was deployed. This can lead to false positives.