# How do NFT marketplaces get NFTs collections to show in the tab 'explore'?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens, nft, erc-721

I'm beginner at `solidity` development, and I have a question:

> How they get NFT collections of various smart contracts to show in the explorer-collection page?
>
> > https://opensea.io/explore-collections

Comment: What do you mean by "explore tab"?

Comment: This section https://opensea.io/explore-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure if this is correct but If I was to make my own marketplace I'd either

1. Check the Contract creation opcode in transactions in a block
2. transfer transactions from the 0x00 address to a wallet in a block
3. you could also listen for events in the blockchain, but i feel is not optimal because you would need to know the deployed contract upfront

Sources for answer 1, 2 and 3:

1. you can find an answer about contract creation tracking [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129737/new-contract-deployment-pattern-0x60c06040), you could just read the transactions in a block and verify if there are transactions with the contract creation opcode in them; If there is a contract creation event; then you can verify if it implements any nft standard by calling its `supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID)` in the contract, you can get more info of the standards here [1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) and [721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)
2. Read the transactions in a block and verify if there are transfers from the 0x00 address to a wallet
3. I think this one is not optimal but there are RPC providers that give you event subscription, ie. event subcription for mints (a mint is basically a transfer), the rpc providers i mention are [infura](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods/subscription-methods) or [alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/notify-api-quickstart), there are more like moralis but I prefer these two; you could take a look and see if anything in these rpc providers help your cause

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to simulate [OpenSea explore tab menu](https://opensea.io/explore-collections) on your own, and you are not familiarize at all with smart contract and `solidity` no worries, when you click on '**/explore-collection**' path to import collections, it shows you several collectios currently they have randomly.

> But before creating a 'tab in  your navbar or menu' to assign a page and show your assets, you need to create or mint this collections first,  and connect each asset with an **administrator address** wallet and the **permissions**.

[image]

> You can create a collection using **[ThirdWeb](https://thirdweb.com/)**, where you can simulate and upload pictures of your original nft to assign them an address, benefactor, comissions of the marketplace, test transactions between your own wallets or mint a new one if you need, how I do in my '**OpenSea clone**' with '**Bored Ape Yatch**' collection clon below.

[image]

> > To test the smart contract flow, I use **[Goerli ETH](https://goerlifaucet.com/)** that is provider and powered by **[Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/goerli-faucet)** how @Casareafer mentioned, which have a faucet of `0.2 Goerli ETH` everyday, as a proposal to use an stable Ethereum Testnet to interact and to practice.

[image]

> Then you can follow the transaction on **[Etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/)** or your wallet (recommendation create a new account from your main account in **metamask** to test).

[image]

> > Assign each contract and project pre stablished in ThirdWeb directly in the code just adding the `address` of the **collection** created:

```js
import { useContract } from '@thirdweb-dev/react'

export default function Component() {
  const { contract, isLoading, error } = useContract("0xa478F76110110fB4cd5CCAA33d0Ac62C3364A021", "nft-collection-name")

  // Now you can use the nftCollection contract in the rest of the component
}
```

**Burn** a single NFT

```js
const result = await contract.burnToken(tokenId);
```

**Mint** many `unique NFTs` at once to a specified wallet.

```js
// Address of the wallet you want to mint the NFT to
const walletAddress = "0x8197b2a89d80010019718e799e1224d4f2b429Ef";

// Custom metadata of the NFTs you want to mint.
const metadatas = [{
  name: "Cool NFT #1",
  description: "This is a cool NFT",
  image: fs.readFileSync("path/to/image.png"), // This can be an image url or file
}, {
  name: "Cool NFT #2",
  description: "This is a cool NFT",
  image: fs.readFileSync("path/to/other/image.png"),
}];

const tx = await contract.mintBatchTo(walletAddress, metadatas);
const receipt = tx[0].receipt; // same transaction receipt for all minted NFTs
const firstTokenId = tx[0].id; // token id of the first minted NFT
const firstNFT = await tx[0].data(); // (optional) fetch details of the first minted NFT
```

> You can find all the rest of the explanation and code in ThirdWeb depending of the project are you simulating, registering with your `email` to be able to connect your **metamask** testnet address.

Comment: I really liked your answer, this platform is very useful. Thanks my friend for the help.