# contracts being deployed via 0x61088480

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, data

Lately I am coming across different deployment tx data patterns. I am already familiar with how the free memory pointer is shifted from the usual 80 when there are immutables in the code ([great explanation here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129737/new-contract-deployment-pattern-0x60c06040)).

However, I have seen a new one in this contract deployment:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe7842e9c9edc0591239fda6b006d11dc0ccbddba9ad2a8bfbc6d53502bed5338

The data starts with **0x61088480**. Reading through the opcodes I have not been able to figure what it is really doing. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: This is not a short answer. Rather an external link to a [series of 6 articles from OpenZeppelin](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deconstructing-a-solidity-contract-part-i-introduction-832efd2d7737) explaining the deconstruction of a Solidity Smart Contract into its assembly bytecode and how deployment and runtime code works.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

Basically `0x61088480` means

61-0884: **PUSH2** 0884

80: **DUP** 0884 from the first stack

You can find the reference [here](https://www.evm.codes/).

Comment: Yes, I understand the opcodes being used here and the data that is being pushed onto the stack by them, and the subsequent operations. My question is WHY is this pattern being used and what changes does it mean versus the usual 0x60806040, that points the free memory pointerto 80 in order to start loading the contract bytecode there. I don not see the meaning of this new deployment pattern I am asking about.